# How to measure procedure/function progress without loop using ReportProgress

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I'm setting up a program which automates an Excel task with vb.net. My code runs in the background. I had used a BackgroundWorker to do that. My problem is in ReportProgress. Since there is no loop in my procedure, I cannot measure executed code / accomplished task. My goal is to show the progress of the task in a ProgressBar.

I had already tried with Timer / ProgressBar, but recently I had seen that a BackgroundWorker is the way to execute a task in the background.

Below is my DoWork code

```
Private Sub BGWB_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BGWB.DoWork
    Try
        Dim STATUS_SG As Workbook = STATUSAPP.Workbooks.Open(STATUSPath, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, [ReadOnly]:=False)
        Dim BK_SG As Worksheet = CType(STATUS_SG.Worksheets("BASE BK"), Worksheet)
        Dim BOOKINGS As Worksheet = CType(STATUS_SG.Worksheets("BOOKINGS"), Worksheet)
```

.
.
.          (REST OF MY CODE)
.
.

```
        BOOKING_SG.Select()
        STATUS_SG.RefreshAll()
        STATUS_SG.SaveAs(SAVESTATUSPath)
        RECTIF_BOOKING.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
        BASE_PLC.Close(SaveChanges:=False)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

As you can see, there is no loop code to measure the progress.

Comment: You could put in your own value to report, for example after the first step you could report a progress of 10%, after the second step a progress of 30%, and so on. Adjust the numbers to make it realistic, although everyone is familiar with a progressbar taking 50% of the time on the last 99% step.

Comment: I agree with Andrew.  I suggest you add some temp code to time how long each step you are doing takes as a percentage of the total time (`BOOKING_SG.Select()` , `STATUS_SG.RefreshAll()`, etc).  Then use that as your progress # as you move through the steps.  It is as close as you are going to get.

Comment: You have no practical way to measure progress or guess how long these steps are going to take.  What you see on your own machine is quite unlikely to repro well on the user's.  The fix is simple, change the progress bar's Style property to Marquee.

Comment: First, thank you everyone for your answer. Yes it's an option to do it manually but I really apreciate if the systeme do it. My question is reportprogress cannot report progress of procedure without loop?

Comment: @PAYNRmrsn It can report the progress, but you have to tell it the amount of the progress to report. It might make more sense to report which step it is on - the user will soon learn how long it will take based on the step number.